# C# Equivalent for the VB.NET ReadFile function

Tags: c#

I have the following in `VB.Net`

```
ReadFile(HidDevice, ReadBuffer(0), (long)(Capabilities.InputReportByteLength), NumberOfBytesToRead, 0);
```

Was wondering what is the equivalent method in C#?

Comment: You just want to read a file using C#?

Comment: That doesn't look like a VB.Net function - it looks more like a Windows API function, in which case you can [use P/Invoke to call it](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/readfile.html?diff=y).

Comment: That's not VB code - VB doesn't have C-style casts or semi-colons.

Answer (score 0):

```
 using (System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader("file location"))
        {
            string content = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

OR

```
 using (System.IO.FileStream fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream("file location", System.IO.FileMode.Open))
        {
            byte[] content = new byte[fileStream.Length];
            fileStream.Read(content, 0, content.Length);
        }
```